# Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Polyline'

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, icons

I am trying to use [this](https://mui.com/components/material-icons/?query=poly&selected=Polyline) material ui icon in react. It has been imported as follows:

```
import PolylineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Polyline';
.
.
return (<PolylineIcon className={classes.icon} />); // Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Polyline'
```

But I get the aforementioned error and npm fails to compile. **What's the problem here?** Knowing that I am using other icons smoothly with no errors; such as:

```
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';
.
.
.
return (<EditIcon className={classes.icon} />); //works fine
```

This compiles fine, so @mui/icons-material module is indeed installed and works.

Dependencies from *package.json*:

```
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.2",
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polyline icon was added later. Update your `@mui/icons-material` to `^5.2.5`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! A follow up: I tried to run `npm install @mui/icons-material` to get the latest version, but I got this error:
`npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\...
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\..`

I searched for solutions and one was to run `npm cache clean --force` before I run the install command, but the problem persisted.

Comment: @AmroAbdelfatah I'm a years-long yarn user, so kind of rusty on npm, but have you tried `npm update @mui/icons-material`?

Comment: Yup. Same error :/

Comment: @AmroAbdelfatah Well if that doesn't convert you to yarn (), next thing I would do is backup+delete package-lock.json and node_modules and try installing again from scratch, hopefully not destroying everything in the process.

Comment: Funny you'd say that... I'm right now fixing the same issue the same way and I'm using yarn! but yeah removed yarn.lock and got it working!

Answer (score 1):

`Polyline` seems to have been added to `@mui/icons-material` in the [release v5.2.0](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.2.0) from this [pull request](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/29818).

You should update `@mui/icons-material` at least to version `5.2.0` to use `Polyline` icon

Comment: Thanks for answering! A follow up: I tried to run `npm install @mui/icons-material` to get the latest version, but I got this error:
`npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\...
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\..`

I searched for solutions and one was to run `npm cache clean --force` before I run the install command, but the problem persisted.

Comment: Try to delete the `node_modules` folder, update package.json by setting the version `5.2.4` to both packages and run `npm install`

Comment: Will try that. Thanks Olivier!